# Why TextView shows text in black on Android Oreo when using Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-emulator, themes, android-appcompat, android-8.0-oreo

I am using Theme.AppCompat as the parent style for my AppTheme theme. This is the contents of my style.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

The problem is when I run my application on a device with Android 6.0 it displays fine, but when on Oreo emulator, it shows like this:
[image]

The text is black on a black background. I have not set any text color or background color, other than using Theme.AppCompat as stated above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your style:

```
<item name="android:textColor">yourColorGoesHere</item>

<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#295055</item>
```

Instead of #295055 you can give any color you want.

Comment: Do let me know if it works, also if it works for you mark this as an answer please. Happy coding bro :)

Comment: to give primary color is not compulsory but you can give it too. Just try both of the lines.

Comment: Thank you! Still does not work. (Maybe a problem with the system image?)